# Could we mute the theme a little?

Tags: feature-request, design, meta

While I get the excitement and everything, the color scheme of this site is quite harsh on the eyes. The white background of the page coupled with the very bright blue header is making it fairly uncomfortable to read the text, specially on the home page (where the text is also a shade of blue).

Could we make the site color scheme a little less bright? The white and blue could be toned down by a bit without deviating from the overall concept.

Comment: Quick fix: `$('.topbar').css('background', '-moz-linear-gradient(300deg, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet)');
$('.topbar').css('background', '-webkit-gradient(linear, left center, right center, from(red), color-stop(14%, orange), color-stop(28%, yellow), color-stop(42%, green), color-stop(56%, blue), color-stop(70%, indigo), to(violet))');
$('.topbar').css('background', '-o-linear-gradient(left, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet)');
$('.topbar').css('background', '-ms-linear-gradient(left, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet)');
`

Comment: `$('.topbar').children().css('background-color', 'transparent');

$('.network-items').css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25)');
$('.topbar-menu-links').css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25)');
$('#search > input').css({
    'background-color': 'transparent',
    '-khtml-opacity': '.50',
    '-moz-opacity': '.50',
    '-ms-filter': '"alpha(opacity=50)"',
    'filter': 'alpha(opacity=50)',
    'filter': 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0.5)',
    'opacity': '.50',
});` Paste that into your JavaScript console.

Comment: Oh gawd. @TheGuywithTheHat what sorcery is this? >:(

Comment: @Undo It mutes the colors! _avoids eye contact_

Comment: Give it about 5 minutes.  Your eyes will adjust.

Comment: `$("div").children().parents().css('background-color', 'red');` this is exactly what you want. Everybody likes  red.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat Yuck! There's already so much here about unicorns. If we make rainbows a meta-meme too, nobody will come here anymore except little girls.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If I were only visiting this site, that would work. Even coming here after seeing Google's *white* home page is quite hard on the eyes. I blame the blue.

Comment: @AdiInbar `$('body > div.container').css('background-color', 'pink');` may help.

Comment: Well done @AsheeshR http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1981769#1981769

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat, does your "quick fix" work with Stylish on Google Chrome? Tks.

Comment: I think it is not just the blue but the font is thin and seems grey to me. Try an edit or add comment and the text is much easier to read - however I accept using Courier font is not going to be an accepted solution to the readability issue

Comment: Note more that the highlit code in these comments is significantly more readable than the plain text